# Importing nested XML using Feeds XPath Parser

Tags: feeds

I have some XML formatted as such:

```
<item>
    <title>Name</title>
    <id>12</id>
    <upgrade>
        <id>13</id>
        <level>2</level>
    </upgrade>
    <upgrade>
        <id>14</id>
        <level>3</level>
    </upgrade>
</item>
```

Ultimately from this example I want 3 nodes:

- Title: "Name (1)" GUID: 12
- Title: "Name (2)" GUID: 13
- Title: "Name (3)" GUID: 14

I'm quite happy to do 2 runs of the file if necessary. I have one importer at the moment which sets up the "Name (1)" items. This works perfectly.

I have a second importer set up which I can successfully create the secondary "upgrade" nodes but only if I use \item\upgrade as the context, at which point I lose the title element so the nodes come through as " (2)", " (3)" etc.

If I use \item as the context like the initial importer, I can't seem to loop through the upgrade XML nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Answered on [drupal.org](https://drupal.org/node/2273763)

Import will need to be done using the context `\\item\upgrade`.

Then to target the title from the parent node, use `..\title`.